# Creating SQL Server trigger to debug database issue

Tags: sql-server, database, windows, triggers

I have a database where one of the columns in one table keeps going blank. There's nothing in our software that can clear that column, so we are quite perplexed how it keeps happening.

Any suggestions on how I can figure this out? I'm thinking of creating a trigger that runs every time this table gets updated, and ideally when that field becomes empty.

But what kind of info can I actually track that will help me figure this out? Can I store the SQL statement that gets run when that update occurs? Can I store the Windows process that is connected to the database?

Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: You would be better off looking at Extended Events to capture statements that are run; a `TRIGGER` would have no awareness of the statement (or batch) that was used to cause it to fire.

Comment: What do you mean by "blank" as well? Do you *actually* mean `NULL` or do you mean a zero length string (`''`)? Should the column be `NULL`able or have a zero length? If not, why not make the column not `NULL`able or put `CHECK CONSTRAINT` on it to not allow the value (`''`).

Comment: By blank I mean ''

Comment: So, as I mentioned, should the column be allowed to store zero length strings? If not, then why not create a `CONSTRAINT` on it to not allow the value `''`?

Comment: That's a great idea and I will implement that, but also need to figure out what's causing this to happen. We have no code in our software that can change that field to ''

Comment: If you implement the `CONSTRAINT` you might find out quite promptly afterwards, @Ray, when you're using start complaining the system isn't working. ;)

Comment: That would work if it was trigged from our software and the end user actually reported the error to us. But if it's triggered from an outside source, we would not be getting any info on how it happened. Is there any way to create a trigger in addition to this constraint that could log when this it is triggered, and capture any info possible about what triggered it? Thanks!

Comment: Again, I would suggest looking into Extended Events.

Comment: Cool, I added that. Combining the constraint with Extended Events is exactly what I need. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could also throw an error from trigger and have your client fail. If your client code is written to handle errors and log them, you can find out what causes the issue that way.

Comment: Not sure I understand, I would throw an error based on what? Thanks

Comment: You would throw an error when your condition occurs (the field gets emptied) so you can fail whatever process does that. This can be done as a temp measure to find the place that causes the condition, provided it is ok to take the risk and fail that process. You can query INSERTED table inside the trigger that gives you a table with incoming updates and if your record is not new and incoming value is empty - throw error

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work, if you create the correct set of columns in some kind of logging table:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE LEN(ProblemColumn) = 0)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO dbo.SomeLoggingTable(cols)
    SELECT getdate(), i.key, buf.* 
    FROM inserted AS i
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_input_buffer(@@SPID, NULL)
    WHERE LEN(ProblemColumn) = 0;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is using a trigger and testing for the specific column being updated with `if update(column)`.

You can then capture some diagnositc data such as the following into a logging table:

```
select @@Spid, r.plan_handle, p.program_name, p.loginame, b.event_info
from sys.dm_exec_requests r 
join sys.sysprocesses p on p.spid=r.session_id
cross apply sys.dm_exec_input_buffer(r.session_id, r.request_id)b
where session_id=@@Spid
```

Comment: This looks like what I'm trying to do. I added the trigger but it looks like our software doesn't have permission, so I get an error "view server state permission was denied on object 'server', database 'master" every time I do anything that updates that table.

Comment: ok, that's because the query is using the sys.dm* views; you can `grant view server state to <login>` to allow permission, even just for the purpose of debugging and revoke it after.